# Is it possible to define a color resource as a darker/lighter version of another color resource

Tags: android

Want to achieve something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="titleTextColor">#3D78CC</color>
    <color name="titleBackgroundColor">lighter version of titleTextColor</color>
</resources>
```

so that just changing the title text color changes the background color, and I dont have to set it separately

Comment: Dude every version of color has hashcode. You can look for it and then set it in colors. This is so simple

Comment: yes but I have to set it separately every time i change the text color I have to change the back ground too.

Comment: well define all colors first then use them. That's how it should be done.

Comment: you want like this . ? if title color is Green then you want like pale green / light green?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan No not just an if, i want to run mathematical operation on the value of titleTextCOlor ans assign the value to titleBackgroundColor from the result of this operation. Or atleast insert "cc" after "#" to whatever the value of titleTextColor is

Comment: as of my knowledge it may possible through code and not through XML.

Comment: Did you got it work.?

Comment: get the color using: getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor); then change R G B values as you wish

Comment: yes I think this is possible only through code, I was hoping for some kind of xml hacks to get something like this, by using run time attributes or something

Comment: this becomes especially important when working with dynamic attributes like `?attr/actionBarSize` for example, What if I want to make my appbar exactly 2 times `actionBarSize` ?

Comment: Excellent question--it's something that I've wanted for a long time.  Unfortunately I don't know of any solution. We will all have to do it the hard (and buggy) way.  Too bad good OOP coding practices don't apply to XML.